# Flex 3: No Blue Focus Ring on Button

Tags: apache-flex, button, setfocus

My button doesn't have a blue focus ring around it, even though it has focus.

I've got a component with a RadioButtonGroup and a Button. After a selection is made in the RadioButtonGroup, focus is switched to the Button. I added click="focusManager.setFocus(myCloseButton)" on the VBox.

After, a radioButton is selected, if the user clicks the spacebar the Button fires. 
So, as I understand it focus was switched to the button. But, the button doesn't get a blue focus ring surrounding it. How do I get the focus ring?

(I have visible="false". I turn them to visible, after some effects are finished. So, don't let that throw you.)

```
<mx:VBox id="radioVBox"  visible="false" click="focusManager.setFocus(myCloseButton)" >
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="rgb1" itemClick="goClickHandler(event); "/>
        <mx:RadioButton  groupName="rgb1" label="{answerA}" value="{answerA}" />
        <mx:RadioButton  groupName="rgb1" label="{answerB}" value="{answerB}" />
        <mx:RadioButton  groupName="rgb1" label="{answerC}" value="{answerC}" />

</mx:VBox>

 <mx:Button id="myCloseButton" label="Close"   
    width="100" height="40"
    fontSize="20" fontWeight="bold" 
    click="closeHandler(event)"   
    visible="false" fontFamily="Verdana"  />
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Are you overriding the styles for Buttons as a class in your CSS?

Comment: have you tried myCloseButton.setFocus()?

Answer (score 1):

You can force Flex show the focus drawing after your component get  focus with something like this:

```
focusManager.getFocus().drawFocus(true);
```

also, you can try someting like:

```
myCloseButton.drawFocus(true);
```

Hope it helps.